# problems with application console in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, console-application, visual-studio-mac

I'm testing this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get locations
        Console.Write("Enter altitude at first location:  ");
        int firstAltitude = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter altitude at second location: ");
        int secondAltitude = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // calculate and print altitude change
        int altitudeChange = secondAltitude - firstAltitude;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Altitude change: " + altitudeChange);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

But when I execute it, in the Output Panel I can not put any value because the code goes directly to the second instruction and crash with null value.
In VS for Windows until I put a vakue the second instruction does not execute
Any idea please?
regards

Comment: Where is the application output being displayed? You cannot enter text if the output is displayed in the integrated Application Output window. You would need to ensure the project options - Run - Configurations - Default - Run on external console is checked. However that should be checked by default for a new Console project if it was created within Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: Not an answer, but I suggest you use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-2.2) rather than `int.Parse`.